# SSAS Cube calculated member totals wrong

Tags: mdx, cube, cross-join, ssas-2008

I am learning on the job. I have a table of minutes spend in each bed. I want to calculate percentage utilisation of the beds. I have created the calculated member in my cube in SSAS 2008

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].UtilisationPercent
 AS avg( 
    crossjoin(
      descendants([bedlabel].[hierarchy].currentmember, [Bedlabel].[Bedlabel])
     ,descendants([Date].[date].currentmember, [Date].[Day])
    )
    ,[Measures].[Utilisation Mins]
   ) 
/ (24*60), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Utilisation Mins] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Bedstay'  ;
```

This actually works fine if i slice by year/month or ward/bed.

But the total utilisation shown in the cube browser is wrong. How can i control the way the utilisation total is calculated? Can i create a calculated member in a way that the crossjoin will work at a higher level than leaf?

```
January 2011    Utilisation %
```

- Bed1  98.86%
- Bed2  88.38%
- Bed3  82.63%
- Bed4  94.67%
- Bed5  85.82%
- Bed6  93.53%
- Bed7  78.78%
- Bed8  85.43%
- Bed9  91.16%
- Bed10 90.93%
- Bed11 92.00%
- Total 894.35%  <--- this is way too wrong.

-- added after MEZ's comment

Ok, thanks for the tip. I tried scoped assignment following this

```
SCOPE([Measures].[Utilisation Percentage]);     
    SCOPE([Date].[Date].MEMBERS);     
        SCOPE([bedlabel].[hierarchy].MEMBERS);     
            THIS = [Measures].[Utilisation Mins] / 
                    (60*24
                    * count(descendants([bedlabel].[hierarchy].currentmember, [Bedlabel].[Bedlabel])) 
                    * count(descendants([Date].[date].currentmember, [Date].[Day]))) ;     
        END SCOPE;     
    END SCOPE;     
END SCOPE;
```

I got the same results as with the crossjoin method. I do not see a difference in AS2008 between scoped assignment result and my old crossjoin method? And it still totals up in surreal numbers that i cannot explain.

Comment: Take a look at this link (having an example ) http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2009/11/scope-problems-with-mdx-calculated-members/. You might need to use the SCOPE function based on your date dimension.

Comment: If you can rebuild that in Adventure Works I will find the solution for you.

Comment: Its embarrassing, but i have never worked with Adventure Works before, and i could not find a capacity example equivalent at a glance now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permutation of what Sourav_Agasti suggested and it works now. I think the avg + the nonemptycrossjoin worked better than avg + coalesceempty.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].UtilisationPercent
 AS avg( nonemptycrossjoin(
       descendants([bedlabel].[hierarchy].currentmember,[bedlabel].[hierarchy].[Bedlabel])
       ,descendants([Date].[date].currentmember,[date].[date].[day]))
       , [Measures].[Utilisation Mins]/ (24*60)), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Utilisation Mins] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Bedstay';
```

This also worked, based on MEZ's suggestion.

```
SCOPE([Measures].[Utilisation Percentage]);
  scope ([bedlabel].[hierarchy].members);
      scope ([date].[date].members);      
          this = avg( nonemptycrossjoin(
            descendants([bedlabel].[hierarchy].currentmember,[bedlabel].[hierarchy].[Bedlabel])
            ,descendants([Date].[date].currentmember,[date].[date].[day]))
            , [Measures].[Utilisation Mins]/ (24*60)) ;
          non_empty_behavior (this) = [Utilisation Mins] ;
      end scope;
  end scope;
END SCOPE;
```

The difference to AS2000 is that i only have to do this, plus specify average as the aggregation method on the calculated measure. I also didn't have multiple hierarchy. The syntax seems much simpler to me.

```
avg(nonemptycrossjoin(descendants([Unit].currentmember,[Unit].[Bed label]),descendants([Date].currentmember,[date].[day])), [Measures].[Utilisation Min]/ (24*60)) * 100'
```

Thank you for all who tried to help!

Comment: Glad you got a solution. Equally flummoxed why this worked and `CoalesceEmpty` didn't. Hope someone could explain.

Comment: I also don't understand why one worked and the other didn't. The best i could find online was this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224802(v=sql.80).aspx however, i don't understand better after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the empty tuples are creating issues. Using `CoalesceEmpty` function will replace EMPTY cells with a 0. Try the code below:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].UtilisationPercent
 AS avg( crossjoin(descendants([bedlabel].[hierarchy].currentmember, [Bedlabel].[Bedlabel]), 
descendants([Date].[date].currentmember, [Date].[Day])), CoalesceEmpty([Measures].[Utilisation Mins], 0) )
/ (24*60), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Utilisation Mins] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Bedstay'  ;
```

Since the `AVG` doesn't seem to be working, check the below script out too:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].a
as 
SUM(
(descendants([bedlabel].[hierarchy].currentmember, [Bedlabel].[Bedlabel]) * descendants([Date].[date].currentmember, [Date].[Day])),
[Measures].[Utilisation Mins]),
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Utilisation Mins] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Bedstay'  ; 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].b 
as
COUNT(
(descendants([bedlabel].[hierarchy].currentmember, [Bedlabel].[Bedlabel]) * descendants([Date].[date].currentmember, [Date].[Day]))
,EXCLUDEEMPTY
),
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Utilisation Mins] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Bedstay'  ; 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].C
AS
[Measures].A/[Measures].B,
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Utilisation Mins] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Bedstay'  ;
```

Comment: The results again looked right at the bed /Jan 2011 granularity, but the total for all beds went through the roof, this time at 1394.35% with this change. It doesn't seem to work. I cannot justify the total mathematically to myself.

Comment: Can you try to get rid of `Non_Empty_Behavior` and check?

Comment: For the individual beds, a = 1440, b = 0 and i have errors on c 1.#inf. I don't think the coding is issue, perhaps it really is the scope. In old AS2000 i could choose the way to sum a calculated member eg Avg. How to do that in AS2008?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but maybe a way to dig into what is happening.

Please try adding the following measure:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].UtilisationCount
 AS Count( 
    crossjoin(
      descendants([bedlabel].[hierarchy].currentmember, [Bedlabel].[Bedlabel])
     ,descendants([Date].[date].currentmember, [Date].[Day])
    )
```

Then in your query add this new measure, on columns, hopefully x,y,z,j,q will be some numbers - what is q?:

```
January 2011    UtilisationCount   Utilisation %

Bed1            x                   98.86%
Bed2            y                   88.38%
Bed3            z                   82.63%
Bed4            j                   94.67%
Total           q                   894.35%
```

Comment: Did add the measure. q=31, since Jan has 31 days. q didn't turn out what i expected either. I am still puzzled. Somehow MDX felt easier in AS2000: i don't remember struggling with this utilisation total then.

Comment: @Pho mdx is more efficient in the latest implementation. The syntax has not changed much.